Diffeomorphism between the closed ball and the Mazur manifold cross the interval (appropriately smoothed)?
Context: Let $M$ be the Mazur Manifold, which is a compact contractible smooth manifold-with-boundary (of dimension $4$) not diffeomorphic to the closed 4-ball $\overline{B_4(0, 1)}$.
It is well-known that $M \times [-1,1]$ is homeomorphic to the closed $5$-ball $\overline{B_5(0, 1)}$, and the interiors of these things are diffeomorphic.
However, I want to know if more is true: is there a diffeomorphism between $M \times [-1,1]$ and $\overline{B_5(0, 1)}$, as smooth manifolds-with-boundary?  Of course the answer is no since $M \times [-1,1]$ is not a smooth manifold-with-boundary, rather it is merely a manifold-with-corners.  This leads me to my more precise question:
Question: is there a function $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ which is positive on the interior of $M$, so that
$$W := \{(x, y) : x \in M, y \in [-f(x), f(x)] \}$$
is a smooth manifold-with-boundary which is diffeomorphic to $\overline{B_5(0, 1)}$ (as smooth manifolds-with-boundary)?

Comments: I suspect the answer is yes (and this kind of thing is obvious to experts which I am not), partially because Mazur in his original paper mentions that he works "combinatorially" but all constructions can be made "differentiable".
Also, I framed the problem for $M$ of dimension 4 for simplicity, but if the statement is true for larger dimensions $k > 4$, I am also interested in that.
Proof sketch for dimensions $\geq 6$: Suppose $M$ satisfies all the properties of the Mazur manifold listed above but it is of dimension $k \geq 4$ (I believe such manifolds exist for all dimensions $k \geq 4$ but I'm not 100% positive).  If we can find such a function $f$, then the corresponding manifold $W$ must be homeomorphic to $M \times [-1,1]$ and thus $\overline{B_{k+1}(0,1)}$.  If $k \geq 6$, then this should imply that actually $W$ is diffeomorphic to $\overline{B_{k+1}(0,1)}$ as there are no exotic $k$-balls of dimension 6 or higher (see here).
As for finding such a function $f$, I would imagine that we can take a positive proper function $h$ on $int(M)$, the interior of $M$, and then define something like $f(x) = 1/\log(1 + h(x))$ [so that at the boundary of $M$, the tangent to the graph of $f$ is vertical].
Regardless, this seems somewhat overkill, and doesn't work for dimensions $4$ or $5$ (where morally it should still be true).

This makes no sense: product of two smooth manifolds with nonempty boundary is not a smooth manifold with boundary, it is a manifold with corners.

@MoisheKohan Exactly, that's why I am NOT asking for a diffeomorphism between $M \times [-1,1]$ and $\overline{B}$.  Rather, I am asking if there is an appropriately smoothed version of $M \times [-1,1]$ (so it becomes a manifold with boundary) diffeomorphic to $\overline{B}$.  Let me know if something was unclear.  Thanks for your interest!

I see. This is called "smoothing out the corners." I think it is explained in Milnor's "h-cobordism theorem" book.

As a cross reference (for those interested): this MO post discusses similar issues (and refers to the appendix of Milnor's "Differentiable manifolds which are homotopy spheres") --- the general strategy is to put an appropriate smooth structure on the manifold with corners: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466014/milnor-s-smoothed-corners-technique-for-a-product-of-manifolds-with-boundary-and
